# Binding with ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to bind values according to the condition mentioned in *ngIf. When I try && operator inside *ngIf, its working mysteriously.

**Code**

```
       <div *ngIf="days.sunday == true">
          <p class="circle ml-3">Sun</p>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="days.monday == true">
          <p class="circle ml-2">Mon</p>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="days.tuesday == true">
          <p class="circle ml-2">Tue</p>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="days.wednesday == true">
          <p class="circle ml-2">Wed</p>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="days.thursday == true">
          <p class="circle ml-2">Thu</p>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="days.friday == true">
          <p class="circle ml-2">Fri</p>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="days.saturday == true">
          <p class="circle ml-2">Sat</p>
        </div>
```

Above condition are working fine. I can print the values accordingly.

```
   <div *ngIf="days.sunday == true && days.monday == true  && days.tuesday  == true && days.wednesday  == true && 
   days.thursday  == true && days.friday == true &&  days.saturday == true">
            <p class="circle ml-2">Everyday</p>
                </div>
```

From above condition, I am trying to print **Everyday** if all condition are true but I am getting printed **sun mon tue wed thu fri sat Everyday**

Comment: So what's wrong? If everything is `true`, then each of the individual checks must also evaluate to `true`.

Comment: How to get printed `Everything` if all conditions are true. I am using && operator but still

Comment: make one simple demo with your code  : https://stackblitz.com

Comment: post your component.ts code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use an **[If/Else](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)** template

- Check **if all days are true**. Then you print only **Everyday**
- **Else** print other days according to their conditions

---

```
<!-- If block for "Everyday" -->
<div *ngIf="days.sunday && days.monday && days.tuesday && days.wednesday && 
   days.thursday && days.friday && days.saturday; else elseBlock">
    <p class=" circle ml-2 ">Everyday</p>
</div>

<!-- Else block for other days "Sun, Mon, etc..." -->
<ng-template #elseBlock>
    <div *ngIf="days.sunday">
        <p class="circle ml-3">Sun</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="days.monday">
        <p class="circle ml-2">Mon</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="days.tuesday">
        <p class="circle ml-2">Tue</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="days.wednesday">
        <p class="circle ml-2">Wed</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="days.thursday">
        <p class="circle ml-2">Thu</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="days.friday">
        <p class="circle ml-2">Fri</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="days.saturday">
        <p class="circle ml-2">Sat</p>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

## Note

`days.sunday === true` is equivalent to `days.sunday` since it's a boolean

Answer (score 1):

For given condition, you have to do same thing to every single day as you did on Everyday.

```html
<div *ngIf="days.sunday == true && days.monday == false && days.tuesday == false &&
days.wednesday == false && days.thursday == false && days.friday == false &&
days.saturday == false">
  <p class="circle ml-3">Sun</p>
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The *ngIf does not automatically come with a "else". So if every condition evaluates to true, then it will go into every branch.

If you do not want it that way then you need to rewrite your conditions.

That behaviour is not special to *ngIf and Angular.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to either show the days that evaluate to `true`, or 'Every day' if everything is `true`.

In your component:

```
everyday = this.days.sunday === true && this.days.monday === true && 
    this.days.tuesday === true && this.days.wednesday === true && 
    this.days.thursday === true && this.days.friday === true && this.days.saturday === true;
```

Then in your view:

```
<div *ngIf="days.sunday === true && everyday === false">
   <p class="circle ml-3">Sun</p>
</div>
... etc.
<div *ngIf="everday === true">
   <p class="circle ml-3">Every day</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  days = { sunday: true, monday: true, tuesday: true, wednesday: true, thursday: true, friday: true, saturday: true };

  isEveryDay() {
    let everyday = true;
    for (let key in this.days) {
      let value = this.days[key];
      if (!value) {
        everyday = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    return everyday;
  }
}

<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<div *ngIf="!isEveryDay()">
    <div *ngIf="days.sunday == true">
        <p class="circle ml-3">Sun</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="days.monday == true">
        <p class="circle ml-2">Mon</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="days.tuesday == true">
        <p class="circle ml-2">Tue</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="days.wednesday == true">
        <p class="circle ml-2">Wed</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="days.thursday == true">
        <p class="circle ml-2">Thu</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="days.friday == true">
        <p class="circle ml-2">Fri</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="days.saturday == true">
        <p class="circle ml-2">Sat</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="isEveryDay()">
    <p class="circle ml-2">Everyday</p>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-everyday)

Answer (score 1):

component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let day of days">
         <div *ngIf="day == 'sunday'">
          <p class="circle ml-3">Sun</p>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="day == 'monday'">
          <p class="circle ml-2">Mon</p>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="day == 'tuesday'">
          <p class="circle ml-2">Tue</p>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="day == 'wednesday'">
          <p class="circle ml-2">Wed</p>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="day == 'thursday'">
          <p class="circle ml-2">Thu</p>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="day == 'friday'">
          <p class="circle ml-2">Fri</p>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="day == 'saturday'">
          <p class="circle ml-2">Sat</p>
</div>
 </div>

 <div *ngIf="alldays == true">
    <p class=" circle ml-2 ">Everyday</p>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
  alldays = true;
   days: any = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday ', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday' ];
```

Base on your alldays flag you can hide and show you want